# Change font-size to fit text width to parent element

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if there is a css only solution to change the fon-size to fit text element width to parent?

For instance, if I have a very small text like "Yes" the font wise would be much bigger as the width of "Yes" sould fit the container parent element () width.

However when there is a "Longer sentence written" then the font size would be smaller, but the content would still fit into the same  container.

Edit: I'm not looking for a responsive solution. The suggested solutions solve the problem of responsiveness, however, what I would like to achieve is simply setting the font-size in such a way that, everything fits into one line of text, but font-size is adjusted accordingly.

Comment: No! There's no CSS only solution. There is a jQuery plugin [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/)